# Проблема с отображением png-файлов в мобильном приложении iOS

Tags: php, ios, xcode, клиент-сервер, мобильные-приложения

Приложение не видит файлов, выложенных на сервер. Ниже представлен первый фрагмент кода, отвечающий за соединение с сервером. Если программа анализирует текстовое название файла для определения его в соответствующий массив, как лучше писать серверную часть? php, json? Пожалуйста, дайте развернутый ответ, мало опыта в этом вопросе. Спасибо!

```
+(NSString*) baseURLForDeviceWithSuffix:(NSString*)suf
{@autoreleasepool{
    NSString *res=@"http://shahan.16mb.com/img/";
    res=[res stringByAppendingString:[self deviceFolder]];
    if(![[suf substringWithRange:NSMakeRange(0, 1)]isEqual:@"/"])
    {
        res=[res stringByAppendingString:@"/"];
    }
    res=[res stringByAppendingString:suf];
    return res;
}}
```

Comment: приложение не видит файл, а вопрос как писать сервер?

Comment: Да, в двух словах проблема выглядит именно так.